# Push Notifications not working on iOS in development mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

For the last 2 days I am trying to get push notifications on an iOS app but without any success. The application is using the correct provisioning profile,application identifier and entitlements. The app is even receiving the didRegisterForRemoteNotification callback which is received upon successful registration. I get the device token from this callback and use it to send this device a notification using Urban Airship and my private server. My application never receives this notification. The notifications are enabled for this application in notification settings.

One thing I could figure out is that I am constantly receiving the following error in my device console

```
Feb 14 03:49:55 unknown amfid[1098] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Feb 14 03:49:55 unknown amfid[1098] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Feb 14 03:49:55 unknown amfid[1098] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Feb 14 03:49:55 unknown amfid[1098] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Feb 14 03:49:55 unknown amfid[1098] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

I tried everything to change the entitlements to fix this error but to no avail. At the end, I just copied the entitlements from the mobile provisioning profile and pasted it in the entitlements file.

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the device and now I am able to receive push notifications even though I am getting the same error in console window.